# Switching between TabGroupActivities

Tags: android, tabactivity

When  i select  child actvity of first tab and after it I select second tab and
when come back on first Tab ,it show that previous child activity of first Tab .But i want to show parent activity of first TabGroup activity.

Comment: Please make it more clear what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the **onResume()** method of your tabActivity. And within this activity call those methods and staements which you have written in your onCretae() method.

```
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
//call the methods you have used in onCreate()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. It is useful for me.

Comment: how about accepting this as an answer if this has helped you. Can you just click on the tick mark you can find on the left corner of this answer.